# LISP : SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable I has no value

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I made a simple test function trying to assign j a value of i by calling (test j 10).
I am getting SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable J has no value.

```
(DEFUN test (j i)
    (LET ((j i))
        (print j)
    )
)
```

Comment: When you do `(test j 10)`, what do you expect the value `j` to be equal to in that call?

Comment: I want it to equal 10

Comment: in your function call `(test j 10)`, before function `test` is evaluated/executed, lisp first has to evaluate arguments. so what is the value of `j` before you call function test? did you set it (using `defparameter` or something)? if not, why you use it? it's like calling a function that you didn't wrote yet. symbol has to evalute to something if you use it in function call.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure if you are aware that the variable `j` in the `let` and `j` defined in the parameters of `test` are two completely different variables. As a true refactoring would be to rename them so that it is clear, here is your code with that ambiguity removed:

```
(defun test (pj pi)
  (let ((lj pi))
    (print lj)))
```

This is exactly the same code since the **new** binding in the `let` effectively makes the old variable with that same name inaccessible for the duration of the let.  The warning will be about `pj` since it is still unused in the function and thus you should consider removing it:

```
(defun test (pi)
  (let ((lj pi))
    (print lj)))
```

Usually having a parameter that is not used is a bug so CL nags about such things. However sometimes you make higher order functions that use functions you pass values. eg.

```
(defun map-assoc (fn lst)
  (loop :for n :from 0
        :for (k . v) :in lst
        :collect (funcall fn k v n lst)))
```

Now imagine you want to make a list of just the keys.

```
(defun assoq-keys (lst)
  (map-assoc (lambda (k v n lst)
               (declare (ignore v n lst))
               k)
             lst))

(assoq-keys '((I . 1) (II . 2) (III . 3) (IV . 4) (V . 5)))
; ==> (I II III IV V)
```

The `declare` statement will supress the error that the other variables passed will not be used, but you must include them as that is the contract made by the `map-assoc` function. For a function that takes their values or perhaps swaps other there are other variables you will be using so passing the values is a good generalization.

Comment: I would add that 'let' creates it's own scope.  So you have global scope, function scope and let scope.  In this case, the let scopes 'j' and 'i' are shadowing the function scope 'i' & 'j'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding how the arguments work. Your `test` function, in its current form, takes two arguments: `j` and `i`. You seem to only use `i`, so there's no reason to pass a second one. Consider

```
(defun test (i)
  (let ((j i))
    (print j)))
```

Then call it simply as `(test 10)`.